How to make sure this component switches between spouses React
I have a React class based component with a nested component that handles a state update given as assignAccountsValue. The issue is, when I change spouses, the selectedAccounts is the same for both spouses, so selecting one spouses' accounts updates the other spouses' too.
const initRegularField = activeSpouse === 'spouse' ? 'initRegular' : 'initRegular2'
const initRegularFromAccField = activeSpouse === 'spouse' ? 'initRegularFromAcc' : 'initRegularFromAcc2'
const initRegAccListField = activeSpouse === 'spouse' ? 'initRegAccList' : 'initRegAccList2'
const initRRIFFromAccField = activeSpouse === 'spouse' ? 'initRRIFFromAcc' : 'initRRIFFromAcc2'

return (
  <AccountsDropdown
    inputs={inputs}
    error={errors[initRegularField]}
    accountList={accountList}
    selectedAccList={inputs[initRegAccListField]}
    excludedList={excludedList}
    savedAccountsValue={inputs[initRegularField] || 0}
    assignAccountsValue={(selectedAccounts, accountsValue) => {
      this.props.dispatch(
        Planning.drawdownUpdateInput({
          inputs: {
            [initRegAccListField]: selectedAccounts,
            [initRegularField]: accountsValue,
          },
          errors: { [initRegularField]: false },
          modified: true,
        }),
      )
    }}
    float
  />
)

